# Proving existence of first infinite ordinal $\omega$ in ZF set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Without using AC, is it possible to prove that $\omega$, first infinite ordinal, exists in ZF set theory?

Answer (score 2):

In ZF, the existence of $\omega$ is asserted by the Axiom of Infinity. You cannot prove it from the rest of the theory.